# tem como colocar mascara em php dinamicamente?

Tags: php

Gostaria de colocar mascaras em campos diferentes, tudo via php, por exemplo:

cnpj - "##.###.###/####-##"

cpf - "###.###.###-##"

cep - "#####-###"

telefone - "(##)####-####"

data - "##/##/####"

não quero usar jquery, nem mascaras em javascript, gostaria de fazer no php mesmo, porque quero usar essas mascaras para formatar dados vindos do banco de dados.

Comment: A expressão "dinamicamente" geralmente é usado quando nos referimos a uma alteração no HTML após este já estar carregado na pagina, então o que você quer é mascarar antes da apresentação do HTML ;)

Comment: Acho meio "desperdício" fazer isso em server-side, irá criar um trabalho desnecessário, que poderia ser facilmente transferido para o cliente, em seu navegador, mas isso é só minha opinião.

Answer (score 29):

função php que coloca formata os campos colocando mascaras.

```
function Mask($mask,$str){

    $str = str_replace(" ","",$str);

    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
        $mask[strpos($mask,"#")] = $str[$i];
    }

    return $mask;

}
```

------------------------ chamada da função ----------------------------

```
$cnpj = '17804682000198';
echo Mask("##.###.###/####-##",$cnpj).'<BR>';

$cpf = '21450479480';
echo Mask("###.###.###-##",$cpf).'<BR>';

$cep = '36970000';
echo Mask("#####-###",$cep).'<BR>';

$telefone = '3391922727';
echo Mask("(##)####-####",$telefone).'<BR>';

$data = '21072014';
echo Mask("##/##/####",$data);
```

Comment: Funcional, limpo e legível. Obrigado!

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado.

Answer (score 22):

Você pode utilizar `vsprintf` da seguinte forma:

```
function format($mask,$string)
{
    return  vsprintf($mask, str_split($string));
}
```

Exemplo:

```
$cnpjMask = "%s%s.%s%s%s.%s%s%s/%s%s%s%s-%s%s";
echo format($cnpjMask,'11622112000109');
11.622.112/0001-09
```

Comment: opção simples e que utiliza recursos já disponíveis no php

Comment: Muito simples e funciona bem. Obrigado.