# Filtragem de palavras em string de texto

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou precisando uma solução funcional, para um sistema que estou fazendo.

Preciso bloquear o cadastro de campo textarea se ela conter algumas palavras na string, exemplo:

Essa é uma descrição breve sobre meu perfil, meu telefone 33 3333-3333, meu email: email@email.com.br, e meu site: www.meusite.com ou meusite.com

Eu quero bloquear, ou seja, não permitir esses itens na string, não quero nenhum tipo de contato, nem telefone, nem email, nem site, nem facebook e nem qualquer tipo de rede social.

Pode ser uma solução em Javascript ou em PHP puro, o que for mais simples e objetivo possível.

Fico aguardando um retorno de vocês!

Att

Alisson maciel

Comment: Possível duplicata de [tem como colocar mascara em php dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25651/tem-como-colocar-mascara-em-php-dinamicamente)

Comment: Já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Tem ideia de como é possível fazer, ao menos? O que sabe sobre expressões regulares?

Comment: Sim, sei um pouco de Expressões regulares eu até estou utilizando aqui, algumas validações e funcionando, só que o meu maior interesse é bloquear o email e dominio na string. E isso não consigo, estou utilizando uma função com strpos, estou utilizando uma função que eu consegui, para validar o campo utilizando o array_merge e o array_intersect, e etc. Mais não consegui bloqueio de URL e E-mail na string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso, uma forma basica seria.

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
  var texto = $(this).val()
  var email = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2,3}/
  var telefone = /^(\(11\) [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$/

  texto = texto.replace(email, 'xxxxxxxxxx')
  texto = texto.replace(telefone, 'xxxxxxx')
  
  $('.result').text(texto)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="result"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Fiz um teste digitando no `textarea`, **"Oi meu telefone é"**, e o resultado foi: **"Oi meu xxxxxxxxxx é"**

Comment: entendi, acho bem interesse, só que eu preciso verificar se o que for digitado é um email, telefone ou um dominio, concorda? Então preciso de mais alguem que possa colaborar com esse seu código, para resolver esssa questão conosco.

Comment: Por que não tenta fazer uma função que limpa caracteres da string, utilizando SQL Injection ?

Comment: @AlissonMaciel a ideia aqui é te dar uma base e você partir dela. Porem, editei minha resposta, você pode fazer o teste colocando um email, eu coloquei `rafael@gmail.com`, e ele coloca `xxxxxxx` no lugar, em questão do telefone, `+99 (99) 9999-9999`, e a mesma coisa acontece. Lembrando que isso é uma forma basica, o interessante é que você modifique conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto Sei entendo Rafael, por isso informei que sua função é bem interessante, só que ainda não é o que eu preciso, pois o que eu realmente preciso, está na minha dúvida, e o que vc postou ainda não responde, mais tem uma implementação.

Comment: kkk, nem vi sua nova mudança, ficou boa demais eu vou testar

Comment: como eu faço pra concatenar varios telefones com jquery? Exemplo:

Comment: vc criou ali a função que o usuario precisa colocar o +55,. suponhamos que ele nao coloque, informe apenas o ddd e o numero, ou apenas os numeros. Mais eu nao quero descartar a expressao regular existente. quero que ela continue, e quero adicionar mais essas, porem na mesma variavel telefone, pra nao ter que ficar montando varias variaveis

Comment: @AlissonMaciel Editei a resposta